# Error: unable to get local issuer certificate (npx)

Tags: node.js, shell, ssl, npm, npx

I am trying to use a package called pipcorn with `npx pipcorn` command and responded with the following error on terminal:

.

```
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'
}
```

versions:

> node: v21.4.0

> npx: 10.2.4

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: fixed your issue, can you fix mine now?